# Access attribute of a javascript object

Tags: javascript

This is drawing me up the wall. Such a basic task such as reading in a text from an attribute of an object:

I've got the below data by scraping a website using `var body = $(response).find("#person-rating");`

```
accessKey: ""
​​
accessKeyLabel: ""
​​
hidden: false
​​
id: "person-rating"
​​
innerHTML: "<a title=\"Learn more about our classification\" href=\"classification.html\"><span class=\"label C\">Class C</span></a>"
​​
innerText: "Class C"
​​
isConnected: false
​​
isContentEditable: false
​​
lang: ""
```

​​But I found it next to impossible to get the value by providing the attribute name. I tried:

```
$(response).find("#person-rating").attr('isConnected');
$(response).find("#person-rating")['isConnected'];
$(response).find("#person-rating")[1]['isConnected'];
$(response).find("#person-rating").isConnected;
$(response).find("#person-rating > isConnected");
```

I ran out of ideas. How can I access the value of an attribute ?

html:

```
<div id="person-rating" class="span6 service-nutshell"><h3><img src="logo/person.png" class="favlogo"><a class="modal-link" data-service-name="person" href="#person">Person</a>
<div id="person-rating" class="service-rating"><a title="Learn more about our classification" href="classification.html"><span isConnected="false" class="label C">Class C</span></a></div></h3>
```

Comment: Can you please post the html too here.

Comment: have you tried `.getArribute()`?

Comment: Using duplicate IDs such as `id="person-rating"` is invalid. Don’t expect jQuery to work with this.

Comment: The `isConnected` attribute isn’t on the `#person-rating` element at all; it’s on the `span[isConnected]`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon  Oh, gosh ... you got it man. Feel free to submit it as an answer and I'll tick it for you.